# Using dynamic named range in VBA for scatter chart labeling

Tags: vba, dynamic, label, scatter, named

I'm trying to make a macro that will change the data labels on a scatter chart to the title of each point. Eg:

[image: Example chart]
<sub>(source: [wiseowl.co.uk](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s130/i2.gif))</sub>

In this case I would like the data labels to show the movie title. The code I used comes from [this website](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s130/excel-charts-data-labels-problem.htm), but my scatter chart has two series of data. I would like to use dynamic named ranges to tell the macro the range of cells where the names are, in my code the dynamic named ranges are FONames & BONames. Here's my code:

```
Sub CreateDataLabels()
'holds the entire film data series in the chart
Dim FilmDataSeries As Series
Dim FilmDataSeries2 As Series
'holds one cell at a time
Dim SingleCell As Range
'holds the full list of cells containing film names
Dim FilmList As Range
Dim FilmList2 As Range
'keeps track of which datapoint we're labelling
Dim FilmCounter As Integer
Dim FilmCounter2 As Integer
'The sheet in which the graph is on
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Datos Gráfico")

'set the counter to start at 1
FilmCounter = 1
FilmCounter2 = 1

'set a reference to the cells containing the list of films
Set FilmList = Range("FONames")
Set FilmList2 = Range("BONames")

'set a reference to the chart data series
Set FilmDataSeries = ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
Set FilmDataSeries2 = ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(2)

'make sure data labels are turned on
FilmDataSeries.HasDataLabels = True
FilmDataSeries2.HasDataLabels = True

'loop over the cells in the list of films
For Each SingleCell In FilmList
    FilmDataSeries.Points(FilmCounter).DataLabel.Text = SingleCell.Value
    FilmCounter = FilmCounter + 1
Next SingleCell

For Each SingleCell In FilmList2
    FilmDataSeries2.Points(FilmCounter2).DataLabel.Text = SingleCell.Value
    FilmCounter2 = FilmCounter2 + 1
Next SingleCell

End Sub
```

I'm getting a 1004 error saying the dimension specified is not valid. When I replace FONames or BONames with an actual range of cells, Eg. Range("A5","A11"), everything works perfectly. How do I use those dynamic named ranges in my code?

Comment: Are the named ranges already defined when you run the code?  The named-Range-setting bit of the code runs fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

What is the definition of your dynamic named range?  I defined a named range for column A like so:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,1)
```

and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For example :

```vb
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
' In order to add label at scatter graph. You must selected a graph before.
' @param void
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub add_label_on_graph()
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim xVals As String
    Dim reponse As Integer

    If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
        reponse = MsgBox("Attention, vous devez au préalable sélectionner un graphique avant de lancer cette commande.", vbExclamation, "Information")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Récupération de la range des données que l'on stocke dans la variable xVals.
    xVals = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula
    xVals = Mid(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, ","), xVals, Mid(Left(xVals, InStr(xVals, "!") - 1), 9)))
    xVals = Left(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, "!"), xVals, ",") - 1)
    Do While Left(xVals, 1) = ","
        xVals = Mid(xVals, 2)
    Loop

    ' Ajoute un label à chaque point du graphique
    For Counter = 1 To Range(xVals).Cells.Count
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).HasDataLabel = True
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).DataLabel.text = Range(xVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value
    Next Counter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```